# Loading different aspx pages into an area without reloading the entire page

Tags: asp.net, navigation

I have written a longer text on this subject posted earlier today. Perhaps the text was too long, so I rephrase it very briefly here:

I want to design a very standard site where the user gets the opportunity to navigate to different aspx pages with the aid of navigation menus (left, top). I do not want the entire page to be reloaded when changing the content page for three reasons: state handling, flickering and bandwidth conservation. I just want to load a new aspx page into a "main content area" with the rest of the site untouched.

What is the best way to achieve this? I must not rely on master pages or not master pages or AJAX or not AJAX. It must not rely on anything specific. I just wonder what the standard method would be to achieve this. It must be a pretty common wish.

Thanks

/DT

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)** for this.

The `<iframe>` tag specifies an inline frame.
An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```